# Проблема с clean() в php

Tags: php

Что такое clean()?
Пример clean($_SESSION["userId"])

Отказывается работать на php 7.0.3

Нагуглил только ob_clean(), к сожалению после простой замены clean на ob_clean не достаточно для работы скрипта. А полное выпиливание из кода помогает. 
На сколько важна очистка буфера.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно clean - это локальная функция вашего скрипта и она используется для очистки массива сессий или для какой то валидации) Попробуйте функцию - unset для очистки сессий